# OSX: Packaging an applescript with an executable and having one run the other

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I'm trying to package an applescript into an existing .app package, and make the applescript run the executable in the same package (which is in the /Contents/MacOS/ directory) with some commandline arguments.

Could someone help me out with the applescript syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
set myPath to the path to me as text
set myPath to myPath & ":folder:cl_util"
```

to get the path to a command line utility in the same folder as your script.